# Mutt - sent and drafts in the INBOX

Tags: email, mutt

I'm using offlineimap + mutt + msmtp to handle my email. I would like to have an unorthodox configuration, where all of my current mail (received, sent, and drafts) reside in the INBOX (or at least a single primary folder) and all the rest to be in the archive. This way I can push emails that I no longer need anymore to the archive and have all my current tasks and things that I need to keep track of easily accessible. Any thoughts on how to do this? Would mutt be the place to do this sort of sorting, or would I want to set up some sort of post-sync hook in offlineimap to take care of shuffling things around?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `.muttrc`:

```
set mbox=imap://imapsrvr/INBOX
set record=imap://imapsrvr/INBOX
set spoolfile=imap://imapsrvr/INBOX
set postponed=imap://imapsrvr/INBOX
```

though I've never seen what mutt would make of the inbox being your drafts folder. I assume it will treat *all emails* in your inbox as drafts (untested).

Comment: That is the way of it. When you set the postponed to the inbox, it says that they are all postponed. Presumably it does not actually look at the D flag in the Maildir files for this.